# How do I validate the input by checking that the input for name is a string and the input for the partId is a long?

Tags: java

```
static Product createProduct() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nEnter new product ");

       System.out.print("  Name: ");
        String n =sc.nextLine();
        while(n==sc.nextLine()){

            if(n !=sc.nextLine()){ 
             System.out.println("ERROR! Please Try again!");
            }
             sc.nextLine();
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would recommend you to read http://tinyurl.com/sohints for a guide on how to write good questions to get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use regular expressions, e.g. read input as strings, then validate that the strings are parsable, then parse.

I do not know what the your requirements for name but I know that long must at least match the following regular expression `^\d+$`.

Here is how you can validate your input:

```
if (Pattern.compile("^\\d+$").matcher(idStr).find()) {
    long id = Long.parseLong(idStr);
}
```

Comment: Except that the parseLong can still fail, even if it passes the regex so we can just avoid the regex and catch the exception since we have to do this anyway.